# Typescript functions as optional parameters in another function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like this:

```js
function fn(variableFunction: (args?: String) => boolean) { //changing to args?: any works but this needs to be String
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass the following functions to the above function.

```js
function something(arg: string) {
  return true;
}

function something2() {
  return true;
}

fn(something); //doesn't like this because arg in something is not optional (and I don't want to make it optional either)
fn(something2);
```

What changes can I make to `fn` to make it work for both the cases?

[TS Playground for the above issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAbgQwE40wIwBsBTALkVRwHMBnAfnIGUpcwqBKRAXgD5F84cEpjCcA3gCgAvhImhIsBIhpwAtsSgALGG0rYq5Gix0dEkxImwaQ2JCxDEA3NNnzo8JCvVaTAJlTiEhZWUDZ22A7OMnJoXhrabOzOKKhxPmy+SUA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer depends on what you plan to do with `variableFunction` inside the implementation of `fn`.  Assuming you want to actually call it on a `string` argument like:

```
variableFunction("hello");
```

Then the right signature for `fn` is

```
function fn(variableFunction: (args: string) => boolean) {
  variableFunction("hello");
}
```

Here, I changed `String` to `string` because [you almost certainly don't mean the wrapper object `String`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object), and I made the `args` argument non-optional.

That will accept both `fn()` calls in your example:

```
fn(something); // okay
fn(something2); // okay
```

It may be surprising that `fn(something2)` is not an error, since `something2` does not take an argument.  But this is [intentionally how TypeScript's type system works; functions of fewer parameters are assignable to functions of more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).  That's because you can always treat `something2` (a function of no parameters) like `something` (a function which ignores its parameters) at runtime.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAKAbgQwE40wIwBsBTAMXGnjAC5FUcBzAZ1qalzAYEpEBeAPkT44cEpjA8A3gFgAUIkRZcBEuUiwEqAEQALYoUJwtXANxyAvnLmh1VREzgBbYlB0xO9bA1bt33RJKIcgrYLiDYSOwgxGaylrLWFBpIDs6ufgBMqFLBiKFQ4ZHY0bHx1mipLm6cpogA9HWIcADWmACe5aiV6ZwZtQ1NrW1AA)